# sdequery.exe: When using functions as column names (-C parameter), how do you escape the comma for functions with parameters?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms

Using [sdequery](ftp://ftp.esri.com/pub/staff/vangelo/se_toolkit/docs/util/sdequery.html), I'm specifically trying to return [`sys_context('USERENV', 'SESSIONID')`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions182.htm). `user` and `sysdate`  work fine. Functions with single parameters work fine.

But as soon as I use a function with multiple parameters, I get:   Error: Stream not found (-107). The [SDEINTERCEPT](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/35704) shows the query columns as 2 columns (split at the comma). Makes sense since the  comma is usually a column delimiter, but how do you escape commas that aren't delimiters?

I've tried preceding the comma with a backslash.  Double commas. Wrapping the entire thing in double quotes. Wrapping the comma in various quote combinations.

**UPDATE**
`USERENV('SESSIONID')` works and gives me what I need, but I'd still like to know if/how you can escape the comma for future reference.